# python: найти значения в txt между определёнными символами и каждое найденное поместить в ячейку массива

Tags: python-3.x

есть текст в txt - надо найти каждое значение и поместить в массив

```
spisok = {"edfiuqasdnflkjqhafdiuqhwufihqwuihe:name:awsefqw:fdqljkhebrfiurhg23r74f2g38gf2gofyugo82f2o8gfo82g74o8gfo82g4o3gf28owgq23hofgh2g:name:werwfd:4hfo82gh4rf83dgfqergwergwergwergwergwerg:name:aqfqwfe:qwefqwfeqwef"}
```

из данного текста надо вытащить значение между :name: и :       и поместить в [0], [1], [2] массива программа должна вытащить [0] = awsefqw,   [1] = werwfd, [2] = aqfqwfe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
re.findall(u':name:(.+?):', spisok)
```